# Find and group all unique versions of a file

Tags: linux, files, diff

I have a convoluted directory structure where there are many copies of `foo.txt`. I'd like to find all copies of this file and group them by their `diff` result, i.e.

```
[type 1]
/bar2/sub1/foo.txt
/foobar/foo.txt

[type 2]
/bar2/sub1/foo.txt
/foobar/foo.txt

[type 3]
/sub3/sub4/sub5/foo.txt
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simple like calculating the md5sum for each file and sorting based on the hash.

```
md5deep -r . | sort

d921223ccbe759a632973962bc15a497  /root/.bash_history
dcac40478a92e87cd08a42a6425acea6  /root/testsrv/keys/04.pem
dcac40478a92e87cd08a42a6425acea6  /root/testsrv/keys/client2.crt
e12f5739f81b08c470f20890304bf53e  /root/.bashrc
e1b23db3d2293b142938c74649d9fa6a  /root/testsrv/list-crl
e4e2818e1ed11a951ed5da4e1a86885a  /root/testsrv/keys/revoke-test.pem
ee8bd2ea88220c877a62e22e36a02d20  /root/testsrv/keys/index.txt.attr
ee8bd2ea88220c877a62e22e36a02d20  /root/testsrv/keys/index.txt.attr.old
```

Comment: Good idea! Any difference between `md5sum` and `md5deep`? Also is there a trivial way to add a newline after the first column differs? (I feel like this may be a job for `awk` but I like the expertise).

Comment: Last time I looked `md5sum` doesn't have any method to recursively process a directory. You could probably use find and xargs to overcome this.  But md5deep is the method I generally use.